# How to use dynamic images from static folder

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have a bunch of images under `static/assets/gear-img`

Now I want to use them dynamically in some components. The component doesn't know which exact image to display. The name of the image will be set by a property from the page.

**This is the snipped from my page:**

```
{#each setup as theGear}
 <Gear name="{theGear.name}" icon="{theGear.icon}" desc="{theGear.desc}"/>
{/each}
```

`theGear` is an object from an array "setup".

`theGear.icon` is a string with the icon name

**This is the snipped from the component "Gear":**

```
<script lang="ts">
export let name: string;
export let icon: string;
export let desc: string;
</script>

<img src="static/assets/gear-img/{icon}.png" alt="" />
```

**Problem:**

It doesn't resolve the image-file under static/assets/gear-img/{filename}.png

**Question:**

How can I dynamically load the images from the static folder without actually importing a specific image?

Thanks for that help!

Answer (score 0):

Try it without `static`, just `<img src="/assets/gear-img/{icon}.png" alt="" />`

[vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory)

> You should always reference public assets using root absolute path - for example, `public/icon.png` should be referenced in source code as `/icon.png`